# nginx rewrite rules in location

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have to redirect the following url:

```
http://wwww.domain.de/dynamic_subdir1/subdir2/subdir3/?querysting
```

to

```
http://www.domoain.de/dynamic_subdir1/static_dir/subdir2/subdir3/file.php?querysting
```

In my configuration:

```
location ^~ /subdir2/subdir3/ {
   rewrite  ^/(.+?)/subdir2/subdir3/ /$1/static_dir/subdir2/subdir3/file.php?$args break;
}
```

but i get allways a 500 internal error and in the error log i can see the following:

```
rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting
```

What is wrong in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're almost there.  Assuming you're trying to *rewrite* this (e.g. not issue a HTTP `redirect`), try anchoring your regexp:

```
   rewrite  ^/(.+?)/subdir2/subdir3/$ /$1/static_dir/subdir2/subdir3/file.php?$args break;
```

Note the `$` at the end of the first pattern.

Comment: I think it's actually the location that needs to be anchored. However, this is a overly complex way to specify the `index` for a path.